# Installing QGIS for Mac OS X?

Tags: qgis, python, installation

I downloaded QGIS MacOS installer version 3.2.  I downloaded and installed Python 3.7 as instructed before I started the installation of QGIS.  I was able to install GDAL but when I try to install QGIS I get the error message that says "QGIS requires Python 3.6."

Does this mean I need to install an earlier version of Python?

If so, which version should I install?

I see there are multiple versions of Python 3.6.

Comment: I don't think the subversion matters, but yes, I think you should install python 3.6(.X), but first uninstall 3.7, having multiple python installs can cause problems.

Comment: I used Python 3.6.6 as recommended and it worked. Thank you!!

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 8):

The minor version matters, it must be 3.**6**. The patch version usually does not (3.6.**N**), but QGIS.org specifies 3.6.5 as a minimum.

You can not use Python 3.7 or non-python.org distributions (note: some people have reported mucking around with symlinks to mimic a standard python.org 3.6 install path to get python 3.6 from homebrew/anaconda working).

From the [download instructions on QGIS.org](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html#mac):

> This package uses the python.org Python 3.6, at least version 3.6.5, the "macosx10.9" build - other distributions are not supported.

As of today, the package you need is:

> Python 3.6.8 - 2018-12-24 [macOS **64-bit** installer](https://www.python.org/downloads/mac-osx/) (NOT the macOS **64-bit/32-bit** installer).

Comment: I missed that "fine print".  Thank you so much.  It worked!

Comment: This should be marked as answer

Comment: As of today, version 3.6.8 is the current one. Answer should point to https://www.python.org/downloads/

Comment: @TelmoPimentelMota you are welcome to edit questions here.